# Java - test which checks if values of a HashMap are correctly copied to ArrayList returns false

Tags: java

I am supposed to write a method which returns all the values of a HashMap in the form of a List.

For context, here are the classes I am using. The class Question is a quiz-like multi-choice question which has multiple answers mapped in a HashMap with the key values being ( a),  b),  c),  etc).

The class `Answer` has the following interface:

```
public class Answer{
    private String answerText= "";
    private boolean correct;

    public Answer(String answerText, boolean correct) {
      this.correct = correct;
      this.answerText = answerText;
    }
...
```

The class `Question` has the following interface:

```
public class Question{
    private String text;
    private double points;
    private HashMap<String, Answer> answers= new HashMap<> ();

    public void addAnswer(String id, String text, boolean correct)
       answers.put(id, new Answer(text, correct));
   }
...
```

Each question has a `text` (the actual question), `points` (the number of points you get for it) and `HashMap<String, Answer> answers` where `String` is the key of the answer( a), b), c) and so on), and the `Answer` is the actual answer (so each key corresponds to one question).

Now, I was given a task to write a method in the class `Question` which returns all answers in the form of a list. I have been given a JUnit test for this method and here is the code of the test:

```
@Test
    public void testGetListAnswers(){
        Question question = new Question("Some question", 2);
        question.addAnswer("a", "first answer", true);
        question.addAnswer("b", "second answer", false);
        List<Answer> answers= question.getListAnswers();
        assertAll(
                () -> assertEquals(2, answers.size()),
                () -> assertTrue(answers.contains(new Answer("first answer", true))),
                () -> assertTrue(answers.contains(new Answer("second answer", false))),
                () -> assertFalse(answers.contains(new Answer("package", false)))
        );
    }
```

And here is the actual method I wrote:

```
 public List<Answer> getListAnswers() {

        ArrayList<Answer> list = new ArrayList<>();

        for(Map.Entry<String, Answer> map : answers.entrySet()) {
            Answer o =  map.getValue();
            list.add(o);
        }
        return list;
    }
```

**What I tried**

I wrote a simple method which uses a for loop to iterate through the set and simply adds every value of the HashMap to an ArrayList.

However, the test fails.

Comment: Does your `Answer` class have `equals` and `hashCode` implemented?

Comment: @user7 it does not!

Comment: @user7 might be on to something... The assertions check if the answers list contains new answers. That will fail because they are different instances!

Comment: I implemented ```equals``` and ```hashCode``` and the test surprisingly(to me) outputs true.

Comment: @l0ner9 check my answer, maybe that clarifies why the test passes

Answer (score 1):

Your method sounds fine.
However the test assertions do

```
assertTrue(answers.contains(new Answer("first answer", true))
```

In the List javadocs following is written to the contains method

> Returns true if this list contains the specified element. More
> formally, returns true if and only if this list contains at least one
> element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)).

Since they create a new Answer instance and there is no equals implementation in Answer, the equals from the base Object class is called. This will return false because the basic equals method compares the references.

> The equals method for class Object implements the most discriminating possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null reference values x and y, this method returns true if and only if x and y refer to the same object (x == y has the value true).

If you implement and override the equals (and hashCode) method in Answer to compare **answerText** and **correct**, the tests should pass.

A quick equals (generated by intellij IDEA) could look like

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof Answer)) return false;
    Answer that = (Answer) o;
    return correct == that.correct &&
            answerText.equals(that.answerText);
}
```